# Syntax of conditional statements in QGIS Field Calculator(s)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I have a shapefile which I need to modify. There is one column "CLASS" with the attributes: "A", "B" and "C". I need to change "A" into "1", "B" into "2" and "C" into "3". I tried it with `case when` function. With one case it's not a problem but how does it work with 3 in row?

Is it also possible to build a model with the `FieldCalculator` function?

---

I guess I figured it out! Is this right?

```
CASE
  WHEN "VSt_K" IS 'E' THEN '5'
  WHEN "VSt_K" IS 'A' THEN '1'
  WHEN "VSt_K" IS 'B' THEN '2'
  WHEN "VSt_K" IS 'C' THEN '3'
END
```

But I can't use this in the modeler `FieldCalculator` function...

Answer (score 17):

If you are calculating a field of **String** type, this is the right syntax:

```
CASE 
  WHEN "VSt_K" = 'A' THEN '1'
  WHEN "VSt_K" = 'B' THEN '2'
  WHEN "VSt_K" = 'C' THEN '3'
END
```

Instead, if it's of **Integer** type:

```
CASE 
  WHEN "VSt_K" = 'A' THEN 1
  WHEN "VSt_K" = 'B' THEN 2
  WHEN "VSt_K" = 'C' THEN 3
END
```

---

**EDIT**

The syntax of the `Advanced Python Field Calculator` in Processing Toolbox is different from that of the standard QGIS Field calculator. So you should write your conditional expressions using Python:

**Global expression:**

```
def getValue(x):
    if x == 'A':
        value = '1'
    elif x == 'B':
        value = '2'
    elif x == 'C':
        value = '3'
    # ...and so on
    return value
```

**Formula:**

```
value = getValue( <VSt_K> )
```

**Note:** it's possible to use the `Advanced Python Field Calculator` in Modeler, however you have to specify the source field(s) directly in its formula, because fields cannot be used as input parameters when using this algorithm. Alternatively, you can define an input String parameter containing the default formula. When you run the model, you can eventually change the source field(s) in the Formula input parameter, thus making the model perfectly reusable with other data.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But do you also know how I could use the field calculator (with the shown syntax)in the modeler?

Comment: I've added further details in the answer, explaining how to do it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I tried but there is one little problem. Now the result is that I just got the "C" changed into "3". When I added the 'elif x == 'D':value = '4' string I only get the "D" changed into "4".

Comment: If you calculate a new field from scratch, it should work as expected.

Comment: I dont know why but when Im running my model now (didnt change anything) it says: 
...return value, FORMULA =value = getValue( )
Failed
Error executing algorithm 0 local variable 'value' referenced before assignment See log for more details

Comment: It seems that you need to type the formula properly: `value = getValue(<VSt_K>)`. And don't forget to calculate the `value` in reference to a field of type `String`. Otherwise, if the field to populate is of numeric type, you need to remove all the apices in the `getValue` function.